# Module '"*.module.scss"' has no exported member in Gatsby + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

- I've followed Gatsby's demo project in their documentation (which is highly overdue for an update).
- I've followed the instructions here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules
- I've added an `index.d.ts` to the `/src` of my project with this content:

  ```js
  declare module '*.module.scss' {
    const content: {[className: string]: string};
    export = content;
  }
  ```

The website compiles fine, however, Visual Studio code shows red files everywhere with the following issue:

```bash
Module '"*.module.scss"' has no exported member 'container'.
```

Here's some sample code with that class.

#### styles.module.scss

```scss
.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width:1000px;
    padding: 0 1.4rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### index.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react"
import { HeadFC, PageProps, graphql } from "gatsby"
import DefaultTemplate from "../templates/default"
import HeroBannerComponent from "../components/HeroBanner"
import {
  container  // <-- error is here
} from "../styles/styles.module.scss"

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <DefaultTemplate pageTitle="Home">
      <HeroBannerComponent></HeroBannerComponent>
      <main>
        <div>
          <div className={container}>

          </div>
          <hr />
          <div className={container}>

          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </DefaultTemplate>

  )
}

export default IndexPage

export const Head: HeadFC = () => <title>Home Page</title>
```

How do I get rid of the error (or ignore it so that I don't have errors throughout my UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have arbitrarily named export declarations but you also shouldn't try as you'd just be opting out of type safety. Better to auto-generate the typings:

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-scss-typescript/

You could also do this one-liner but you'd get `any` and not `string` (not recommended):

```
declare module '*.module.scss'
```

Comment: I'm using Gatsby 5.5.0. That plugin isn't compatible with this version. I used the Gatsby CLI and chose Typescript/SASS in the creation options.

Comment: Ah, doing it via a ts plugin like https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules is an alternative

Comment: I could do that, but according to Gatsby docs (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules), webpack doesn't do tree shaking. Therefore, Gatsby recommends importing the individual classes versus the entire styles file. (Sorry, again, I new to Gatsby/React, so just trying to figure out what's best practices.)

Comment: Actually, looking again at the docs, I think if you are using `gatsby-plugin-saas` you can just configure the loader like so: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules:~:text=share%20the%20same-,cssLoaderOptions,-property. I.e. add the `cssLoaderOptions` to it.